# $ \frac {p_1 \cdot \frac{1}{n}}{p_1 \cdot \frac{1}{n} + p_0(1-\frac{1}{n})} = \frac{1}{1+a(n-1)} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$a = \frac{p_0}{p_1}$

$$ \frac {p_1 \cdot \frac{1}{n}}{p_1 \cdot \frac{1}{n} + p_0(1-\frac{1}{n})} = \frac{1}{1+a(n-1)} $$

Could somebody kindly give some points as to how the left equation is simplified to the right? After doing the multiplications, I still can't work it through. I've plucked in some random numbers and verified that both equations have the same output. Below are what i've came to after the multiplications;

$$ \frac {\frac{p_1}{n}}{\frac{p_1}{n} + (p_0-\frac{p_0}{n})} = \frac{1}{1+\frac{p_0}{p_1}(n-1)} $$

$$ \frac {\frac{p_1}{n}}{\frac{p_1}{n} + p_0-\frac{p_0}{n}} = \frac{1}{1+\frac{p_0n}{p_1} - \frac{p_0}{p_1}} $$

Kindly advise

Answer (score 2):

$$ \frac {p_1 \cdot \frac{1}{n}}{p_1 \cdot \frac{1}{n} + p_0(1-\frac{1}{n})} = \frac {n\cdot p_1 \cdot \frac{1}{n}}{n\cdot p_1 \cdot \frac{1}{n} + n\cdot p_0(1-\frac{1}{n})}=\frac {p_1}{p_1 \ + p_0(n-1)}=\frac {\frac{p_1}{p_1}}{\frac{p_1}{p_1} \ + \frac{p_0}{p_1}(n-1)}=\frac{1}{1+a(n-1)} $$